# SQL Server Instead of Update Trigger Using Update 'Where' Clause Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I think I'm close on this one, I just can't seem to get it right.  I've also looked through a lot of questions and answers and either I can't find the answer or I don't understand the questions of others so, please forgive if this is a re-post.

What I want to do seems pretty basic as far as the idea of an "Instead Of" trigger goes.  I'm working in SQL Server 2008.  I have a view that can't be updated directly so I need an Instead Of Update trigger to update one of the underlying tables.  The primary key of the table in questions will not be included as part of the Update statement so I have to select using a foreign key.

I'm trying to get the foreign key supplied in the Where clause of the Update statement but I must be using the wrong syntax.  I'm pretty sure that I must be able to get 'Where' values since they seem likely to be used as keys to underlying tables.  So, given the statement...

```
UPDATE table1 SET field1 = 'value1' WHERE key_field = 'key_value'
```

How do I access get the 'key_value' inside my trigger definition?  I've tried the following...

```
DECLARE @pk INT
SELECT @pk = p_key
  FROM dbo.ptable p, UPDATED u
 WHERE p.f_key = u.key_field
```

And this as well...

```
DECLARE @pk INT
 SELECT @pk = p_key
   FROM dbo.ptable
  WHERE f_key = (SELECT key_field
                   FROM UPDATED)
```

But neither of these seem to work for me.  I'm pretty sure I'm getting the update value correctly using...

```
DECLARE @uValue VARCHAR
SELECT @uValue = field1
  FROM UPDATED
```

I want to be able to use the derived primary key for an insert or update like this...

```
INSERT INTO dbo.xtable (fieldx) VALUES (@uValue) WHERE p_key = @pk;
```

or

```
UPDATE dbo.xtable SET fieldx = @uValue WHERE p_key = @pk;
```

Hopefully, I'm making sense and I'm not too far off.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: its been long time for me that i worked with trigger.. but isn't there is something like inserted is what you use?

Comment: create trigger cascade_utrig
on titles
for update as
if update(title_id)
begin
     update titleauthor
           set title_id = inserted.title_id
           from titleauthor, deleted, inserted
           where deleted.title_id = titleauthor.title_id
     update roysched
           set title_id = inserted.title_id
           from roysched, deleted, inserted
           where deleted.title_id = roysched.title_id
     update salesdetail
           set title_id = inserted.title_id
           from salesdetail, deleted, inserted
           where deleted.title_id = salesdetail.title_id
end

Comment: First, there is no "UPDATED" pseudotable, there are only the INSERTED and DELETED pseudotables.  UPDATES should have an equal number of rows in each.  Secondly, your trigger needs to handle the possibility that more than one row is updated at a time.  Thirdly, we will probably need some table/column definitions and example input, source and result rows to help you effectively.

Comment: SELECT key_field FROM UPDATED : looks strange , is it really what you tried ? or pseudo code ?

Comment: And finally, there is no practical way for your trigger to get the content or elements of the UPDATE command that caused it to fire.  You must implement your trigger in a data-driven manner using the contents of the INSERTED and DELETED pseudotables to determine the changes to make.

Comment: @RBarryYoung : you can use UPDATE(column) to test modification of a column

Comment: @AlainRastoul: Yes, but that has nothing to do with what the OP is trying to do here.  UPDATED is not used as a function, has no column-parameters, and is being treated as a rowset-source (like INSERTED and DELETED).  Its not even spelled the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MSSQL triggers, you have two pseudo tables: INSERTED (new records) and DELETED (old records) . Your problem is that you are trying to read one value from UPDATED (does not exists), plus they may be several records not one.
You should use UPDATE FROM (MSSQL specific) , ie something like

```
UPDATE MyOtherTable
SET ...
FROM INSERTED INNER JOIN TableToFindPk ON  INSERTED.FK = ...
INNER JOIN MyOtherTable ON ...
```

difficult to say more without explanation or little sql code

Comment: So, your saying that even though the trigger is based on an Update command the pseudo table is INSERTED?

Comment: And so it is.  Seems a bit strange that the pseudo table on an Update command would be INSERTED but that's how it is.  I changed my UPDATED to INSERTED and worked through some other minor issues and got it working.  Thanks Alain!

Comment: SQL server logic for those pseudo tables is: INSERTED is used for INSERT and UPDATE triggers :new records for INSERT, new values for UPDATE. DELETED is used in DELETE and UPDATE triggers: deleted records for DELETE, old values for UPDATE.So in a trigger for UPDATE you have old values in DELETED table an new values in INSERTED table.